# Using xsl when to test for attribute values

Tags: xml, xslt

Am using `<xsl:when>` in my code.I need to test values for 2 different attributes in the  "when" condition below i.e.(`<xsl:when test="??">`)
How do i do that please?

I tried this,but it does not work:

```
<xsl:when test="@Attrb1[.!=''] and @Attrb2[.!='']">
```

Also, this gives an error too:

```
<xsl:when test="@Attrb1 !='' and @Attrb2 !=''">
```

msxml3.dll error '80004005'

error '80004005'
Expected token 'eof' found '!='. @Attrb -->!=<--'' and @Attrb2 !=''

Code:

```
<xsl:when test="Condition1"> 
<xsl:choose> 
    <xsl:when test="??"> 
         <xsl:value-of select="somtext1"/> </xsl:when> 
    <xsl:otherwise> 
          <xsl:value-of select="somtext2"/> 
</xsl:otherwise> 
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:when>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use instead:

```
<xsl:when test="@Attrb2!='' and @Attrb2!=''">
```

Comment: Jim, I had tried it earlier before posting this question.It does not work.Have edited my question.Thanks.

Comment: Based on the error message `Expected token 'eof' found '!='` I strongly suspect you have a mismatched quote somewhere.  There's no way it should expect EOF at that point. Use a decent editor that understands XML (Notepad++ is a reasonable start) and pay attention to the syntax coloring.

Answer (score 1):

Or use:

```
<xsl:when test="not(@Attrb1='') and not(@Attrb2='')">
```